# torch.nn has no attribute named upsample

Tags: python, pytorch

Following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-perform-neural-style-transfer-with-python-3-and-pytorch#step-2-%E2%80%94-running-your-first-style-transfer-experiment

When I run the example in Jupyter notebook, I get the following:

[image]

So, I've tried troubleshooting, which eventually got me to running it as per the github example (https://github.com/zhanghang1989/PyTorch-Multi-Style-Transfer) says to via command line:

```
python main.py eval --content-image images/content/venice-boat.jpg --style-image images/21styles/candy.jpg --model models/21styles.model --content-size 1024 --cuda=0
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 287, in <module>
main()
File "main.py", line 44, in main
evaluate(args)
File "main.py", line 242, in evaluate
stylemodel = Net(ngf=args.ngf)
File "/root/styletransfer/PyTorch-Style-Transfer/experiments/net.py", line 284, in init
model += [upblock(ngf*expansion, 32, 2, normlayer),
File "/root/styletransfer/PyTorch-Style-Transfer/experiments/net.py", line 127, in init
kernelsize=1, stride=1, upsample=stride)
File "/root/styletransfer/PyTorch-Style-Transfer/experiments/net.py", line 167, in init
self.upsamplelayer = torch.nn.Upsample(scalefactor=upsample)
AttributeError: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'Upsample'
```

I can't figure out how to get past this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason maybe that you have an older version of PyTorch on your system. On my system, the pytorch version is 0.2.0, `torch.nn` has a module called `Upsample`.

You can uninstall your current version of pytorch and [reinstall it](http://pytorch.org/).

Comment: The tutorial lists that it requires 0.1.12_2, which is what I already had installed. I messed about a bit and this did seem to fix it. I cant run it through Jupyter for some strange reason, but can through command line (same commands). Thanks.